How to generate access token from azure OAuth 2.0 token (v2) endpoints?
I want to get an access token from given URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
I am passing the following parameters, as mentioned in he Microsoft docs: client_id, scope, client_secret, grant_type, resource and audience.
When I hit this URL, I get a "403 Forbidden" response.
When I try the same from Bruno, it succeeds:

But not from my code:
public HttpStatusCode InvokeWebAPIPostJson(string apiBaseURL, string urlSuffix, SaveCommentModel saveCommentModel)
{
    var token = WebAPIControllerExtensions.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(this.configuration, ApplicationConstants.AUTHORITY_BASEURI, ApplicationConstants.GRANT_TYPE, ApplicationConstants.SCOPE, ApplicationConstants.CONTENT_TYPE);
    double cltTimeout = ApplicationConstants.HTTPCLIENT_TIMEOUT;
    var url = apiBaseURL ?? string.Empty;

    using var httpRequestClient = new HttpClient();
    httpRequestClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cltTimeout);
    httpRequestClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    string saveComment = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveCommentModel);
    var stringvar = "\"" + saveComment + "\"";
    StringContent jsonContent = new(saveComment, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var resp = httpRequestClient.PostAsync($"{urlSuffix}", jsonContent).Result;
    var statusCode = resp.StatusCode;
    return statusCode;
}

// getting the token by using htis below method:

        public static string GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(
            IConfiguration configuration, string authBaseURL, string grantTypeStr
            , string scopeStr, string contentType)
        {
            var audienceVal = configuration["Keyvault:Audience" + string.Empty] ?? string.Empty;
            var clientIdVal = configuration["Keyvault:ClientId" + string.Empty] ?? string.Empty;
            var secretVal = configuration["Keyvault:Secret" + string.Empty] ?? string.Empty;
            var tenantVal = configuration["Keyvault:Tenant" + string.Empty] ?? string.Empty;

            var audienceId = configuration.GetValue<string>(audienceVal) ?? string.Empty;
            var client_id = configuration.GetValue<string>(clientIdVal) ?? string.Empty;
            var client_secret = configuration.GetValue<string>(secretVal) ?? string.Empty;
            var tenantId = configuration.GetValue<string>(tenantVal) ?? string.Empty;

            string authorityUri = $"{authBaseURL}{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
            string grant_type = grantTypeStr;
            string scope = $"{scopeStr}";
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "client_id", client_id },
                    { "scope", $"{client_id}/.default" },
                    { "client_secret", client_secret },
                    { "grant_type", grant_type },
                    { "resource", client_id },
                    { "audience", audienceId }
                };

            list.AddRange(values);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(list);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(authorityUri),
                Content = content
            };

            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType) { CharSet = "UTF-8" };
            var clt = new HttpClient();
            var result = clt.PostAsync(authorityUri, content);
            var resultContent = result.Result.Content;
            var bearerData = resultContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var bearerToken = JObject.Parse(bearerData)["access_token"].ToString();

            return bearerToken;
        }
    }
}

How to get / generate access token from azure OAuth 2.0 token (v2) endpoints?

You should also get a message with the 403 response telling you what is wrong. Use Fiddler or another network sniffer to see the exact HTTP request sent out by your C# code and compare that to Bruno.

That is the endpoint to access (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token)
Assuming you have your Azure AD credentials stored in anappsettings.json file. You should parsing your token correctly, those answer is parsing to access your token
update:
{
    var token = WebAPIControllerExtensions.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(this.configuration, ApplicationConstants.AUTHORITY_BASEURI, ApplicationConstants.GRANT_TYPE, ApplicationConstants.SCOPE, ApplicationConstants.CONTENT_TYPE);
    double cltTimeout = ApplicationConstants.HTTPCLIENT_TIMEOUT;
    var url = apiBaseURL ?? string.Empty;

    using var httpRequestClient = new HttpClient();
    httpRequestClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cltTimeout);
    httpRequestClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
    httpRequestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    string saveComment = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveCommentModel);
    var stringvar = "\"" + saveComment + "\"";
    StringContent jsonContent = new(saveComment, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var resp = httpRequestClient.PostAsync($"{urlSuffix}", jsonContent).Result;
    var statusCode = resp.StatusCode;
    return statusCode;
}

// getting the token by using htis below method:

public static string GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(
    IConfiguration configuration, string authBaseURL, string grantTypeStr, string scopeStr, string contentType)
{
    var clientIdVal = configuration["Keyvault:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty;
    var secretVal = configuration["Keyvault:Secret"] ?? string.Empty;
    var tenantVal = configuration["Keyvault:Tenant"] ?? string.Empty;

    var client_id = configuration.GetValue<string>(clientIdVal) ?? string.Empty;
    var client_secret = configuration.GetValue<string>(secretVal) ?? string.Empty;
    var tenantId = configuration.GetValue<string>(tenantVal) ?? string.Empty;

    string authorityUri = $"{authBaseURL}{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    string grant_type = grantTypeStr;
    string scope = $"{client_id}/.default";

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "client_id", client_id },
        { "scope", scope },
        { "client_secret", client_secret },
        { "grant_type", grant_type }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri(authorityUri),
        Content = content
    };

    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType) { CharSet = "UTF-8" };

    using var clt = new HttpClient();
    var result = clt.PostAsync(authorityUri, content).Result;
    var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var bearerToken = JObject.Parse(resultContent)["access_token"].ToString();

    return bearerToken;
}```



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Hi @joana I am getting same forbidden error.

As we changed the scope to default-"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", we are getting 401 unauthorized.
